# I want to SUM of all top1 Record Quantity?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to sum all top1 record. Here Item101,Item102,Item103 are rows That has following numbers. I need to sum of all top 1 records.

```
Item101 = 300,200,100
Item102 = 150,140,130 
Item103 = 95,85,75
```

The result I'm expecting is,

```
Result= 300+150+95
```

Comment: You have to give more details about what `Item101`, 102, etc. are. Is this code that you pulled into Java using SQL? Are they rows in a sql table? Please provide more details.

Comment: It's typically better to represent sample data for SQL questions in a [tabular format](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and "top 1" is non-standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: I am using sql server 2014.

Answer (score 0):

use aggregate function `max()`

```
select max(Item101)+max(Item102)+max(Item103)
from table_name
```

Comment: it will nth row not only 3 rows. That is I have 1 to n item. each item has serialno that is unique. each serial number has multiple quantity of click record as below. That is Item 1 has serial no Item101 and click quantity are 300,200,100 per month. also Item 2 is Item102 has 100,90,80. also nth item is Item103 has 95,85,75 . I need to sum all items top1 or max number of Table

Comment: @MdShahnawaz . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you have asked.  I would suggest that you try writing a *clear* question, with sample data and desired results as *text tables* in the question.  You can also set up a db fiddle to further elucidate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if Item101,Item102,Item103 are column name it would be :

```
 select top 1  Item101+Item102+ Item103
 from Table
```

Comment: the SQL tag on this website is about ANSi/ISO SQL standards not about SQL Server (MSSQL)..

Answer (score 0):

If Item101,Item102 and Item103 are columns and data is stored in ',' seperated in 3 different rows, Then you can try this.

```
select cast(SUBSTRING(item101,1,charindex(',',item101)-1) as int)  + 
       cast(SUBSTRING(Item102,1,charindex(',',Item102)-1) as int )  +
       cast(SUBSTRING(item103,1,charindex(',',Item103)-1) as int ) from YOURTABLE
```

This give output as  **545**

Comment: it will nth row not only 3 rows. That is I have 1 to n item. each item has serialno that is unique. each serial number has multiple quantity of click record as below. That is Item 1 has serial no Item101 and click quantity are 300,200,100 per month. also Item 2 is Item102 has 100,90,80. also nth item is Item103 has 95,85,75 . I need to sum all items top1 or max number of Table